# Can we have a theorem that makes Pythagoras numbers without any error? #proof

Tags: number-theory

Can we have a theorem that makes Pythagora's numbers without any errors?

Comment: What are Pythagoras numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I assume that by "Pythagorean number" you mean "Pythagorean triple" - that is, you're looking at generating triples $(a,b,c)$ such that $a^2+b^2=c^2$.*

The answer is yes. In fact, the situation is as good as possible: we have a formula which enumerates *only and all of the* Pythagorean triples, and a proof that it works.

---

First, the easy part - generating lots of triples:

> For $0<n<m$, the triple $$a=m^2-n^2,\quad b=2mn, \quad c=m^2+n^2$$ is a Pythagorean triple.

This is easy to prove: $$a^2+b^2=(m^4-2m^2n^2+n^4)+4m^2n^2=m^4+2m^2n^2+n^4=(m^2+n^2)^2=c^2.$$ So immediately this gives us a way to generate infinitely many Pythagorean triples easily.

---

It takes a bit more work to get every Pythagorean triple. First, note that the method above *doesn't* get all triples - e.g. it won't produce $a=9, b=12, c=15$ *(check this!)*. We can fix this by throwing on another parameter:

> Given $0<n<m$ and arbitrary $k>0$, the triple $$a=k(m^2-n^2),\quad b=k(2mn), \quad c=k(m^2+n^2)$$ is a Pythagorean triple; moreover, every Pythagorean triple has this form.

The proof that this always gives a Pythagorean triple is identical to the previous argument (just factor away the $k$s); the proof that every triple is gotten this way (which really just boils down to showing that every primitive triple was gotten the original way) [takes more work](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_triple#Proof_of_Euclid's_formula) - and in particular isn't just a direct algebraic simplification - but is still elementary.

Comment: The ancient Babylonians compiled large tables of Pyth. triplets, presumably for practical applications. We don't know whether they knew the general formula, or, as a historian said, they may have just been good at arithmetic.

Comment: Thank you so much! But what can we find this way basically?(Not just solving from our considerations)

Comment: @MathProblems I don't understand that question. Are you asking *how* one could have come up with this on one's own?

Comment: Thank you so much! But what can we find this way basically?(Not just solving from our considerations) I mean For 0<n<m, the triple
a=m2−n2,b=2mn,c=m2+n2
is a Pythagorean triple.
This is easy to prove:
a2+b2=(m4−2m2n2+n4)+4m2n2=m4+2m2n2+n4=(m2+n2)2=c2.

But why did we choose a,b,c like that?

Answer (score 1):

Pick any odd number “A”. “B” = (AA+1)/2, “C”=B-1.

A,B and C are Pythagorean numbers.

Comment: Now pick any even number “A”. “B” = (A/2)^2 +1, “C”=B-2. A,B and C are Pythagorean numbers.

Comment: What is your mathematical reason?

Comment: @MathProblems Just check directly that $A^2+C^2=B^2$ (note the switch-up!) whenever $A$ is odd (respectively even), $B={(A^2+1)\over 2}$ (resp. ${A^2\over 4}+1$), $C=B-1$ (resp. $B-2$). For example, if $A$ is odd, then we get $A^2+C^2=A^2+({A^2+1\over 2}-1)^2=A^2+({A^4+2A^2+1\over 4}-(A^2+1)+1)={A^4+2A^2+1\over 4}=B^2.$ (The "$A$ is odd" bit is needed to ensure that $B$ and $C$ are each positive integers; similarly, in the "$A$ is even" case we need $A$ to be even in order for the $B$ and $C$ so defined to be positive integers.)